# Changing the home screen on S4 vs 5.0.1

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

How can I change my homepage on the S4 new software version 5.0.1? I don't like the update, the colors and how things have changed. Normally I'm all for an update but this sucks!

Answer (score 0):

You can install a new launcher, such as [Google now launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.launcher&hl=en_GB), if you do not like the new Touchwiz layout.

Comment: Keep in mind that this might render some Touchwiz specific functionality unuseable if the replacement launcher was not explicitly compiled for Touchwiz.